# On clicking the hyperlink inside gridview, it should redirect to a page and on the target page, fetch the data depending upon the ID

Tags: gridview

If I click on a hyperlink button within gridview, it should redirect to a different page (along with the ID as reference).

On the target page, it should fetch all the data depending upon that ID.

I am a newbie and could not find good understandable links on internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put hyperlink in the grid like the following:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlView" runat="server" Text="View" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/pageredirect.aspx?id=" + Eval("Id") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

You can find more contents on EVAL and BIND on the following URL:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366(v=vs.100).aspx

Just have a look. I hope it will help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a RowCommand event to the GridView.

```
 <asp:GridView onRowCommand="GvRowCommand" ID="GridView1" runat="server">
         <asp:TemplateField>
               <ItemTemplate>                                                                    
                   <asp:LinkButton Text="Click" ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" 
                       CommandArgument='<%# Eval("SomeId") %>'/>                                                                    </ItemTemplate>                                                            
</asp:TemplateField>  
</asp:GridView>
```

C#

```
   protected void GvRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
   {
      var someId = e.CommandArgument;
      Response.Redirect("Target.aspx?id="+someId.Tostring(),false);
   }
```

You can refer msdn for more : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.. I am clear with the code behind

Comment: But asp:LinkButton cannot be added inside gridview right? It accepts only asp:HyperLinkField but does not accept ID, CommandArgument etc